# MapPoint Control - Adding territories

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mappoint

Anyone know if it is possible to add territory to map using map point control in C# application? (Something like in normal MapPoint 2010 application) If so, how I can use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to use the `Datasets` collection's `LinkTerritories()` method.

The "dataset loading" methods (eg. to create pie charts and shaded area maps) are a bit of a hairy area in MapPoint's API. With their many parameters they are easy to get wrong and the resulting error message is less than useful - typically just "bad parameter". So be warned!

Comment: Hi, but using LinkTerritories I have to read data from file. Is it possible to create territories (for example connected with post codes) without using any files? I would prefer to have a table with post codes and just add territoried to these post codes.

Comment: As with other datasets (excl. Simple pushpin datasets limited to Notes and Names), I believe you are limited to either invoking the relevant Wizard, or making the underlying call that the wizard uses. Ie. You have to load from a file.

Comment: It really works:), and do you know if I can change color of the territory in code?

Comment: Good you've got further with particular little bit of functionality Thant I've tried. I need to experiment with it and write an article. Re. Colors (and other properties), I think you are probably stuck with the parameters to LinkTerritories. Alternatively look at the Datasets object documentation but I don't recall seeing anything there.